# Browse for folder dialog

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I need to know how to get the "browse for folder" dialog in java. I am aware of SWT. But I need to do in swing? Is there any solution to this?

[As we start on eclipse it will ask for choose workspace. We can see the browse for folder dialog at that time]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible with AWT (without customizing an own DirChooser) ?

Comment: Simply: JFileChooser + setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY)

Answer (score 54):

You can force JFileChooser to select only folders, if you add the following command.

```
        _fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode( JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
```

in the snippet that Bibhaw posted.

Answer (score 28):

```
JFileChooser j = new JFileChooser();
j.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
Integer opt = j.showSaveDialog(this);
```

Comment: "this" in ShowSaveDialog is your JFrame variable

Answer (score 24):

Pre-chewed code:

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
fc.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File(".")); // start at application current directory
fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
int returnVal = fc.showSaveDialog(this);
if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    File yourFolder = fc.getSelectedFile();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use JFIleChooser.
e.g.

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser("C:\example");
```

for details please go through:

http://leepoint.net/notes-java/GUI/containers/20dialogs/30filechooser.html

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html