# Is there a Eclipse plugin for a File Browser Dialog button?

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, eclipse-plugin

I have searched the web for quite a while now, and have not come across a simple solution for making a button, which opens a file browsing dialog in an Eclipse program. I am using WindowBuilder at the moment, and it seems odd to me, that one has to do so much to add a simple "Browse..." button to their GUI.

I hope someone can help me on this matter, thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779360/browse-for-folder-dialog
If this could help.

Comment: To select a file to open / close use the SWT `FileDialog`

Comment: Review my answer, i've change it becuase i pasted a wrong code :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this code:

```
 private Button browse;
   browse = new Button(outerGroup, SWT.PUSH);
        browse.setText("Browse ...");
        browse.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false,1,0));
        browse.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                DirectoryDialog dialog = new DirectoryDialog(shell, SWT.NULL);
                String path = dialog.open();
                if (path != null) {
                    //do stuff with path
                }
            }

        });
```